# INF CopyFiles Directive - Copy Cursors To Non-Default Folder

Tags: windows, setup, mouse-cursor

I'm using [this INF template](http://hamzanetwork.blogspot.com/2014/04/install-custom-cursor-scheme-for-windows.html) that installs cursors to "C:\Windows" using the DIRID 10. My problem is that I want to install the cursors on "C:\NonSystemFolder" (ideally using %SystemDrive%).

I used a shortened version of the template to test the absolute path DIRID, and tried to pass the environment variable %SystemDrive% to it so that it would copy my file in the system drive (with no folder). What it actually did was creating a folder named "%SystemDrive%" on the current path and putting my file inside that folder.

```
[Version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"

[DefaultInstall]
CopyFiles = Scheme.Cur

[DestinationDirs]
Scheme.Cur = -1,"MyCursors"

[Scheme.Cur]
Working In Background.ani
```

I checked the [non-exhaustive list of DIRIDs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-dirids) that Microsoft provides in their site, but aside from -1 (absolute path) any other ID than seems to describe what would work for me. As mentioned previously, though, the -1 ID doesn't do what I assumed it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I re-read Microsoft [documentation of the DIRIDs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-dirids) and found out that DIRID 24 was exactly what I was looking for. The description had a rather odd wording, so at first I disregarded it as the right one to use.

Here is the revised INF template  for a custom folder at the system drive (usually "C:"). In order for it to be used for your specific cursors you need to change the File names under [Scheme.Cur] and [Strings]. Comments were added to make it easier.

```
[Version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"

[DefaultInstall]
; DIRID 24 is used throughout the file. That is the same as %SystemDrive%.
; Lines starting with semicolons are comments and are here just to help with editing.
CopyFiles = Scheme.Cur, Scheme.Txt
AddReg    = Scheme.Reg


[DestinationDirs]
Scheme.Cur = 24,"%CUR_DIR%"
Scheme.Txt = 24,"%CUR_DIR%"

[Scheme.Reg]
; Don't mess with this!
HKCU,"Control Panel\Cursors\Schemes","%SCHEME_NAME%",,"%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%pointer%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%help%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%workback%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%busy%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%cross%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%Text%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%handwrt%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%unavailiable%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%Vert%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%Horz%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%Dgn1%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%Dgn2%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%move%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%alternate%,%24%\%CUR_DIR%\%link%"

[Scheme.txt]
; Put here text files that you want to copy to the folder containing your cursors.
; READ ME.txt ;<-sample

[Scheme.Cur]
; Here goes the list of file names of your cursors. Order is irrelevant.
aero_arrow.cur
aero_helpsel.cur
aero_working.ani
aero_busy.ani
aero_select.cur
aero_unavail.cur
aero_ns.cur
aero_ew.cur
aero_nwse.cur
aero_nesw.cur
aero_move.cur
aero_link.cur
aero_cross.cur
aero_pen.cur
aero_up.cur

[Strings]
; This is the relative folder where cursors are going to be copied.
CUR_DIR       = "MyCursors\Windows Aero"
; This is the name of your Scheme. The one that will show up in Mouse Properties
SCHEME_NAME   = "Windows Aero"
; All the names within quotation marks MUST MATCH with the file names in Scheme.Cur. String names to the left should match equivalent cursors in the right.
pointer       = "aero_arrow.cur"
help          = "aero_helpsel.cur"
workback      = "aero_working.ani"
busy          = "aero_busy.ani"
text          = "aero_select.cur"
unavailiable  = "aero_unavail.cur"
vert          = "aero_ns.cur"
horz          = "aero_ew.cur"
;dgn1 is the one going from top-left to bottom-right
dgn1          = "aero_nwse.cur"
;dgn2 is the one going from top-right to bottom-left
dgn2          = "aero_nesw.cur"
move          = "aero_move.cur"
link          = "aero_link.cur"
;cross or precision selection
cross         = "aero_cross.cur"
handwrt       = "aero_pen.cur"
alternate     = "aero_up.cur"
```